# Prevent drag outside QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qtreeview, qtreewidget

In a QTreeWidget I want to be able to reorder items using InternalMove AND receive drops from another tree in my application.

If I set `dragDropMode` to `InternalMove` I cannot drop items inside it. However, if I set it to `DragDrop` it lets the user drag items out of the my QTreeWidget.

Is there a way of preventing this? Is there another way around the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not worried about drags outside of your application, maybe setting the `DragDropMode` of the **other** `QTreeWidget` in your application (or anything that derives from `QAbstractItemView` for that matter) to:

```
treeWidget->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragOnly);
```

is enough to get the desired behavior. This does not prevent the items of the `QTreeWidget` in question from being dragged, but they cannot be dropped in the other tree, while you can still drop them (and the items from the DragOnly tree) into the tree that accepts drops. Does this help? (Admittedly not the most intricate way to attack the problem but performing some local tests it seemed to work)